# Datatables(jquery plugin) not populating table with AJAX, valid JSON being returned

Tags: php, json, datatables, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to populate this HTML table with DataTable jquery plugin, using an AJAX call receiving this JSON from the php script,

Response from the server:

```
{
    "newsletters": [{
        "anio": "2016",
        "mes": "1",
        "quincena": "1"
    }, {
        "anio": "2016",
        "mes": "1",
        "quincena": "2"
    }]
}
```

HTML file:

```
<div id="tabla_newsletters" >
     <table id="newsletter_datatable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>anio</th>
                <th>mes</th>
                <th>quincena</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

     </table>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   


            var table = $('#newsletter_datatable').DataTable( {
                ajax: {
                    url: '/newsletter/getNewsletters',
                    dataSrc: 'newsletters'
                },
                columns:[
                          { 'newsletters': 'anio' },
                          { 'newsletters': 'mes' },
                          { 'newsletters': 'quincena' }
                    ],    
            } );

    });
</script>
```

and then my php service(made in symfony 1.4), as I stated before this is returning a correct JSON according to a JSON online validator:

```
 public function executeGetNewsletters(sfWebRequest $request){

    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();

    $qry=$conn->execute("Select anio,mes,quincena from newsletters");

            $newsletters = $qry;

            $dataNews = array();
            $i=0;
                foreach ($newsletters as $news)
                    {

                           $dataNews[$i] = array(
                                "anio" => $news['anio'],
                                "mes" => $news['mes'],
                                "quincena" => $news['quincena'],
                            );
                      ++$i;
                    }

            $output = array(
                "newsletters" => $dataNews,
            );

            $json=$this->renderText(json_encode($output));
            return $json;




  }
```

Datatable throws the following error:

"DataTables warning: table id=newsletter_datatable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

I look at other cases but they were different cases at a first glance.....

EDIT: I already solved it....the problem was on the script on the server, the indexes needed to be numbers....now it's populating the table correctly

Final code:

-Response from the server now is(apparently the plugin accepts only this format from what I've seen with other people's bugs):

```
{"newsletters":[["2016","1","1"],["2016","1","2"]]}
```

-HTML file code is:

```
<div id="tabla_newsletters" >
     <table id="newsletter_datatable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>anio</th>
                <th>mes</th>
                <th>quincena</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

     </table>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   


            var table = $('#newsletter_datatable').DataTable( {
                ajax: {
                    url: '/newsletter/getNewsletters',
                    dataSrc: 'newsletters'
                }
            } );

    });
</script>
```

and php service code is(I've only changed the indexes of the associative arrays from field names to numbers):

```
public function executeGetNewsletters(sfWebRequest $request){

    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();

    $qry=$conn->execute("Select anio,mes,quincena from newsletters");

            $newsletters = $qry;

            $dataNews = array();
            $i=0;
                foreach ($newsletters as $news)
                    {

                           $dataNews[$i] = array(
                                "0" => $news['anio'],
                                "1" => $news['mes'],
                                "2" => $news['quincena'],
                            );
                      ++$i;
                    }

            $output = array(
                "newsletters" => $dataNews,
            );

            $json=$this->renderText(json_encode($output));
            return $json;




  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI : You could have solved your original problem simply by doing it right :

```js
columns:[
  { data: 'anio' }, //NOT  { 'newsletters': 'anio' }
  { data: 'mes' },
  { data: 'quincena' }
],
```

Use `data` to define which attribute from each newsletter item that should go into the column.